# What is a common practice in rename a variable/function in sublime (Golang)?

Tags: go, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

One of the advantage of static typed language is the tooling for refactoring. As for the `Golang`, I think simply a `rename` tool which can work across files is enough. Is there such a tool / plugin for sublime text editor?

Currently available approach:

- `Ctrl-D` multi-cursor selection, works fine within a file.
- `gorename` works in the command line. Is it possible to do the rename
  in sublime (without switching to the command line and back)?

Answer (score 1):

Search/replace over files is something Sublime Text supports I believe. Would there be anything wrong with that?
e: [man subl](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_files.html)